# How do i make the value in the int variables to drop down each itertion by 10?

Tags: c#

```
for (int x = data.Count() - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myGifList.Count; i++)
    {
        img = Image.FromFile(myGifList[i]);
        int imgWidth = img.Width;
        int imgHeight = img.Height;
        img = resizeImage(imgWidth - numeric, imgHeight - numeric, myGifList[i]);
        img.Save(mainpath + "\\" + data[x] + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(myGifList[i]), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
}
```

The first loop is working good.

```
imgWidth = 512
imgHeight = 512
numeric = 10
```

So first loop i change all files resolution to 502x502 in this line:

```
img = resizeImage(imgWidth - numeric, imgHeight - numeric, myGifList[i]);
```

Now what i wanted to do is since i did imgWidth - numeric and imgHeight - numeric so now the imgWidth is 502 also imgHeight is 502 so now in the next itertion i want to drop it down by 10(numeric) again so now the files resolution will change to 492x492 next itertion minus 10 again so 482x482 and so on.

The problem is im making inside the innder loop:

```
int imgWidth = img.Width;
int imgHeight = img.Height;
```

So they will allways be 512x512 and minus 10 allways be 502x502

EDIT**

1. I added a breakpoint on the line:

   for (int x = data.Count() - 1; x >= 0; x--)

But it never stop there i saw x is getting down each time from 50 to 49 to 48...but it never stop on this line why ?

1. In the inner loop:

imgWidth and imgHeight each = 512

numeric = 10 ( declared it in the constructor )

And data is a List contain directories. The first directory name is:

```
SecondProcess_-Width = 502 Height = 502
```

All the files should be first change to resolution 502x502 and to be saved to the directory SecondProcess_-Width = 502 Height = 502

This is working the problem is that after it loop over all the files in myGifList it will save to the directory: SecondProcess_-Width = 492 Height = 492 the same resolution as before 502x502 and it should be 492x492.

And so on next directory is SecondProcess_-Width = 482 Height = 482 so the resolution should be 482x482.

I have already the directories the problem is saving the files with the correct resolution each time.

Comment: Do you simply mean `x-=10` ?

Comment: Where is the declaration and definition of numeric?

Comment: Edited my question explained more and what i tried.

Comment: Marc yes to change each time the resolution of all the files by - 10 and save them all to directory next all of them minus 10 again save to directory...so if they were 502x502 next time 492x492 next time 482x482. The problem is how to make it - 10 each time. But not in each directory from 502 to 2 but in first directory all files 502x502 in next directory all files 492x492 in the last directory all the files will be 2x2 and ofcourse when it get to 2x2 it should stop so it wont be -12x-12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you edited the question. You need to reduce the images as the directory changes.

Use the formula:

```
(50 - x) * numeric
```

It will give you the following results:

- For x = 49
- 50 - 49 = 1
- 1 * numeric = 10

Then you can simply subtract `reduceBy` from `imgWidth` and `imgHeight`:

```
img = resizeImage(imgWidth - reduceBy, imgHeight - reduceBy, myGifList[i]);
```

Use this code snippet:

```
for (int x = data.Count() - 1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    int reduceBy = (50 - x) * numeric;

    for (int i = 0; i < myGifList.Count; i++)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Shaharyar i tried but that will put all the files in the directory where the first file is 502x502 and the last file is 2x2 and it will keep make the minus untill i get exception since it cant be less then 2x2 since it will be minus resolution. What i need is in the inner loop to make the same resolution for all files first all files in myGifList should be change to 502x502 and to be saved as 502x502 then the outer loop x will be now 49 and now the inner loop should change all the files in myGifList to 492x492 and save them in the current directory as 492x492 then x = 48.

Comment: The problem is i added a breakpoint on the outer loop with the x and it never stop there once it get into the inner loop i see with a breakpoint in the inner loop that x is getting down 50,49,48 but it never stop on the line: for (int x = data.Count() - 1; x >= 0; x--)

Comment: Edited my question explained more and what i tried.

Comment: What is the type of the `List`?

Comment: String. data and myGifList are both type string.

Comment: So you want to that the first directory should contain the images of resolution 512, then second directory 502 and so on... and you have 50 directories so the last directory will contain images of resolution 2x2?? Because every time you will reduce the resolution by 10, and it will be 50 times, so the last directory images will be reduced by 10x50 = 500 pixels. Did I get your problem correctly?

Comment: Yes you right. In fact data contain 51 indexs thats 51 directories in index 0 the directory is SecondProcess_-Width = 2 Height = 2 and in index 50 the directory is SecondProcess_-Width = 502 Height = 502 thats also what i have on the hard disk this directories and all the directories between them in 10's. The resolution of the original files is 512x512 and you were right this is what i want.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I hope it'll solve your problem. If you still have any problem, feel free to ask.